# Flash messages in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble with the flash messages in Rails 4.
I'm doing the one month rails and when I try to login to a page or try to log out, I don't get any flash messages? Could it be the browser?

This is the code for the flash messages in application.html.erb

```
            <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
               <% content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
            <% end %>
```

I'm on ubuntu 14 and I'm using Firefox/Chrome

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong erb tag, and that is why the `content_tag` is not showing up.  It should be:

`<%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>`

Not the difference in the `<%` that you had and the `<%=` that I included above.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
```

The equals is important.  It tells rails to display it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<%=` instead of `<%`

First one will be treated by Rails template engine as Ruby code to be executed and sent to output, while second one only be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code in application layout...

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
<%= content_tag(:div, msg, :id=>"#{name}", :class `enter code here`=> "alert alert-  info") %>
 <%end%>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
   </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function() 
 {
$("#notice").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function()
{
$(this).remove();
});
}, 5000);
</script>
<%= yield%>
```